# Object #<Object> has no method 'http' when using neo4j and bluebird

Tags: neo4j, bluebird, node-neo4j

I am using [this](https://github.com/thingdom/node-neo4j/tree/v2#readme) Neo4J library and I would like to use promises instead. So I tried using bluebird's promisify. I created the following code...

```
    var db = new neo4j.GraphDatabase('....'),
        Promise = require('bluebird'),
        Cypher = Promise.promisify(db.cypher);

    var query = [
        'MATCH (node)',
        'OPTIONAL MATCH (node)-[rel]->( )',
        'RETURN DISTINCT node as node, collect(rel) as links'
    ].join('\n');

    var i = 0
    var onSuccess = function (results) {
            res.json(parseGraphResponse(results));
        },
        onFail = function (err) {
            console.log("Error " + err);
        };
    Cypher({
        query: query
    }).then(onSuccess).catch(onFail);
```

However, now I get the following error that is captured onError...

> TypeError: Object # has no method 'http'

This version works fine...

```
    db.cypher({
        query: query
    }, function (err, results) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error " + err);
            return;
        }
        res.json(parseGraphResponse(results));
    });
```

A little more investigation shows that it is blowing up on this code...

```
GraphDatabase.prototype.cypher = function(opts, cb, _tx) {
  ...
  // Blows up here....
  return this.http({
        method: method,
        path: path,
        headers: headers,
        body: body,
        raw: true
      }, (function(_this) {
        return function(err, resp) {
          ...
        }
      })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet this will fix it:

```
Cypher = Promise.promisify(db.cypher.bind(db));
```

For future reference, the way to debug this is to interpret the error message as saying that `this` doesn't have an `http` method, but you know `db` does, so `this` must not be set to `db`. And indeed, passing `db.cypher` loses the `this` reference to `db`.

Comment: Ahh gotcha so it is the whole lost context. Maybe this is a pull request to neo then because it seems to me that they should be using something like `var _this = this`. Wouldn't that also prevent it? (of course change `this.http` to `_this.http`)

Comment: That wouldn't help in this case either: because by the time the function runs, `this` has been lost, so `var _this = this` wouldn't help. An alternative is for node-neo4j to proactively `bind` `GraphDatabase.prototype.cypher` to each instance when it's constructed. That tends to be an anti-pattern in JS for performance, but maybe not a big deal here in practice. Food for thought!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer I would recommend adding the following...

```
if(db.cypher)
  Promise.promisify(db.cypher.bind(db));
```

the if will prevent failure if the DB is down. In my case I use an XML file to mock data when I can't reach the server.